# Problema en añadir el código para un filtro de búsqueda en ORACLE APPLICATION EXPRESS con sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo el siguiente script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este script me permite realizar consultas de la base de datos `CATALOGOS.cat_aps` mediante filtros de busqueda acorde a los campos registrados como: `Cod_institucion_aps`, `credencial_aps` y los demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada filtro de busqueda se asocia a su campo en la base de datos, pero al momento de añadir el código para el filtro de busqueda relacionado con el campo `CODIGO_SOS` dejan de funcionar los otros filtros.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: El código se comparte como texto para que se pueda probar. Las respuestas serán como texto para no ponerte a transcribir. Lo otro, no sé cómo funciona exactamente Oracle Application Express pero pinta que: **a)** no es un campo de una tabla sino un resultado que generas al manipular info y el formulario no puede mapear búsquedas sobre eso (cómo buscas sobre el regexp?), o **b)** ese triple regexp es muy lento